# Simple nodejs example with multiple files

Tags: node.js

I wrote very simple project on NodeJS. I want to make similarity to other language programming example, such as java. So I make: server.js, main.js and module (calc.js). Here are their code:

**File server.js**

```
var main = require('./main');

var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    main.main(req, res);
}).listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
```

**File main.js**

```
var calc = require('./calc');

exports.main = function(req, res){
    var a = 5;
    var b = 9;
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end(calc.Plus(a,b));
    res.end(calc.Minus(a,b));
};
```

**File calc.js**

```
(function(){
    module.exports.Plus = function(a, b){
        return a+b;
    };

    module.exports.Minus = function(a, b){
        return a-b;
    };
}());
```

I run it on my server, and I got an error:

> Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/
>   _http_outgoing.js:558
>       throw new TypeError('First argument must be a string or Buffer');
>       ^
>
> TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer
>       at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.end (_http_outgoing.js:558:11)
>       at Object.exports.main (D:\workspace\FirstNodeJS\main.js:7:6)
>       at Server. (D:\workspace\FirstNodeJS\server.js:5:7)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       at Server.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:546:12)
>       at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)

I am just a newbie with NodeJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues to your problem.

First problem is that the `.write(...) API from NodeJS's response object takes in a string buffer or string.

**Quote:**

> response.write(chunk[, encoding][, callback])
>
> chunk < **string** > | < **Buffer** >
>
> encoding
>
> callback  Returns:

**See:** https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback

Your calculation methods `Plus` and `Minus` are returning Integer. Hence you need to convert the Numbers to String before writting;

**Example:**

```
var calc = require('./calc');

exports.main = function(req, res){
    var a = 5;
    var b = 9;
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    var result = calc.Plus(a,b);
    res.write(result.toString());
    res.write("\n");
    result = calc.Minus(a,b);
    res.write(result.toString());
    res.end();
};
```

Also, problem number 2 is that you should only call `.end(...)` once for each response object.

You should either build your result and then call it. Or call `.write(...)` as many times as you need and when you are happy then close the communication by calling `.end(...)`.

Another thing, you might want to line break `\n` your results so that the output looks like;

[image]

If not it will be a one liner, `14-4`.

Comment: Can you tell me which tool are you using for dev nodejs? (in your screenshot)

Answer (score 2):

`res.end()` expects the first argument to be a string or a buffer.  You are passing a number.  That is how it is described in the doc [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback).

You could do:

```
res.end(calc.Plus(a,b).toString());
```

Also, you can only call `res.end()` once for a given response.  If you want to send multiple things as part of the response, you can either combine them all into a string before using `res.end()` or you can call `res.write()` multiple times and then finish it with `res.end()`.